# Using Android Services, onStartCommand being accessed at a weird time

Tags: android, service, gps

I am trying to create an app that gives me the GPS coordinates when a photo is taken. Because the GPS needs to be accurate I am running it as a service to get the best lock. However when the main activity is opened the `startservice()` in `onCreate()` does not access the onStartCommand in GPSClass.

It runs the `onStart()` and then is for some reason triggered to access that class after finishing both starting procedures.

Why is this happening? It seems so illogical. By the way, I have been trying to walk through using debugging.

**Main activity start up code**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent GPSstart = new Intent(this, GPSClass.class);
    this.startService(GPSstart);

}

private void GPSrunner() {
    Intent GPSstart = new Intent(this, GPSClass.class);
    this.startService(GPSstart);

    // check GPS is onstart
    if (!GPSClass.isGPSon()) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
}

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GPSrunner();

  }
```

**Service Code**

```
public class GPSClass extends Service implements LocationListener {

private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
private static LocationManager locationManager;
private static boolean GPSOn;
private static Location location;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    GPSOn = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}

@ Override
public void onDestroy() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

public static boolean isGPSon() {
    return GPSOn;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<service android:name=".GPSClass" 
        android:exported="false"
        />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing a lot of research and this is the best answer that I have.

Android activities start services after they have completed onCreate and onStart commands, therefore I found an alternative way to gather the information that I needed for my project.

This conclusion was backed up by another post that I found [Android Service never appears to start - onStartCommand() not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689891/android-service-never-appears-to-start-onstartcommand-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you declare your service in the manifest?

```
<application

  .
  .
  .

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:label="My Service" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: sorry, i did just it didn't print that section when I posted the question, And I can get the service to work, it just is working after all the calls in onCreate and onStart have happened

Comment: @emmistar why are you using in both onCreate and onStart?

Comment: I am using the onStart() for if the activity is restarted so that it opens GPS again. I may actually change that later down the track.

Comment: @emmistar try to use onCreate method instead of onStartCommand in the service, like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service

Comment: @emmistar or take a look at this example: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ maybe can help you out