# Android Service OnStartCommand not working

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to create a simple service in android.

I checked the Settings->application tab and I can see that the service is running. Unfortunately OnStartCommand function is not getting executed. I can't even see the toast message.

Here is my code:

**service class**

```
public class CertisServices extends Service {
    GPSTracker gps;
    private double latitude = 0;
    private double longitude = 0 ;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    public int OnStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){


        get_my_gps_location();
        String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Services started : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            send_data(lati, longi);


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void OnDestroy (){
        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Services stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void send_data(String lat, String lng){
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Your URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.16.110.3/agent_tracking/index.php/api/rest/get-schedules/");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Your DATA
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lng));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response;
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void get_my_gps_location(){

        gps = new GPSTracker(CertisServices.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();


        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            //gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }
}
```

**Main activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CertisServices.class));
```

I don't get any error messages. Can anyone help me to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Service never appears to start - onStartCommand() not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689891/android-service-never-appears-to-start-onstartcommand-not-called)

Comment: a `Service` **does not** have such method: `OnStartCommand`

Comment: also, don't use `Toast`s for debugging: use `Log.d` instead

Comment: @pskink tnx. i tried with Log.d also, its not logging anything.

Comment: because there is no such method: `OnStartCommand` to override, use `@Override` annotation to make sure you are overriding some base method, like this `@Override onStartCommand(...`

Comment: Tnx @pskink that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pskink say you have a typo in your service code. Try to rename `OnStartCommand` method to `onStartCommand` (and also `OnDestroy` to `onDestroy`).

If it don't fix your issue, you should check if you declared your service in the manifest :

```
<service android:name="your.package.CertisService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a log instead of toast. The OnStartCommand() might be executing but sometimes(In my case never) the toast messages never appear. Try to debug the service.