# How to play .mp4 video as a background video in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have watched many tutorials but somethings wrong. I have simple mainactivity and there is a VideoView on the it's layout. I downloaded a video from youtube as a .mp4 file size is about 10 mb. I found a great sample about videoview on youtube as the following link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPeDn18FrGY&t=75s

ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private VideoView bgVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bgVideo=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bg_videoview);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bgvideo);

        bgVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
        bgVideo.start();

        bgVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use genymotion emulator. While i run the app i take "can't play this" error. And at the android monitor things like this.

```
06-07 03:16:28.675 2146-2146/com.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
06-07 03:16:28.675 2146-2146/com.sample D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
06-07 03:16:28.692 2146-2146/com.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
06-07 03:16:28.692 2146-2146/com.sample D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
06-07 03:16:28.709 2146-2146/com.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
06-07 03:16:28.709 2146-2146/com.sample D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
06-07 03:16:28.742 2146-2146/com.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-32)
06-07 03:16:28.742 2146-2146/com.sample D/VideoView: Error: 1,-32
06-07 03:16:28.758 2146-2146/com.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
06-07 03:16:28.758 2146-2146/com.sample D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
06-07 03:16:29.526 2146-2146/com.sample I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719403/play-video-in-background-using-mediaplayer-in-service).

Comment: Try to run on device rather than emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MediaPlayer` object and play in one service. here is the example code:

```
public class Mp3PlayerService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {

    /** Android Built-in Media Player */
    public MediaPlayer player;

    /** Binder for Mp3 Service */
    private final IBinder iBinder = new Mp3PlayerService.BackgroundAudioServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
          playSongLocal();
          playSongNetwork();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void playsongLocal() {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        player.reset();
        try {
            LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "playing aaa.mp3");
            afd = getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("aaa.mp3");
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void playsongNetwork() {
        player.reset();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(networkUrlLink);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return iBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
        player.release();
    }

    /** return itself when beeing asked */
    public class BackgroundAudioServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public Mp3PlayerService getService() {
            return Mp3PlayerService.this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start bgVideo.start inside onPrepare

```
bgVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                bgVideo.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    MainActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(bgVideo);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bgvideo);

            bgVideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            bgVideo.setVideoURI(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
bgVideo.requestFocus();

    bgVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    bgVideo.start();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry result is the same!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to start bgVideo after onPreparedListener?

```
bgVideo.setVideoURI(uri);

        bgVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

        bgVideo.start();
```

Also what API versions are you using?

Comment: I use android 7.0 API 24.

Comment: @Timosis Did you try to use video.start after onPreparedListener?

Comment: Yes but the result is same.

Comment: i caught this.

Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: Did you try other video?

Comment: Did you put the video in `raw` folder?