# Videoview in background

Tags: android

I have a Video as background of my Activity A, when I open Activity B like this

```
 Intent in = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(in);
```

When I finish the Activity B like this:

```
ActivityB.this.finish();
```

The Activity´s A Background (the video) is not playing, the background is black, how can I solve it? thanks

Comment: try to use `service` for playing your video in background

Comment: sorry, can you give me an example? thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719403/play-video-in-background-using-mediaplayer-in-service , and about services https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html ,

Answer (score -1):

use on pause and on resume in activity A

```
    onpause{
mvideoview.stopplaying
}

onresume{
mvideoview.start
}
```

this will solve your problem