# How to wait until services stops in Android

Tags: android, android-service, splash-screen

Can I wait until my all services stops? I try to make a splashscreen in my android application and I want it to wait until all my services stopped.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
        }
```

I try this example of code...My problem is that I do not know how to continuously checking this in my splashscreen activity.
Or maybe it is not a good solution.

Comment: What are you doing in a splash screen that takes so long you need a service? You should use an AsyncTask for one-off processes like this.

Comment: html, json, xml downloading and parsing...

Comment: Check this answer... it helped me... 

[a good explanation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3055749/2149135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a normal `Service`, Use an `Intent service`, as it automatically stops itself after completing its task.

Now when this service stops, you may send a `Local Broadcast`, and receive this `Broadcast` in your Splash `Activity`.

Keep a track of running services, and one which have stopped, you may use flags for this.

So for example if service A stops itself and sends a broadcast set its flag to `true`.

Now  on each `Broadcast` receive check if all flags are true, if Yes, stop the Splash screen and move to next step or else wait for other services to stop.

**Example**

We have three services A, B, C running and corresponding to them we have three flag stopA, stopB, stopC in our Splash Activity.

Now when A finishes, it sends a local broadcast, which is then received in Splash Activity, now we set the flag of A i.e `stopA = true`; and check if flags for services B & C are true or not (i.e. if other services have stopped or running)

If `true` finish this activity, else wait for other broadcasts.